# Можно ли отправить значение .html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть вот такой ужасный код:

```
 $('#select_znak').click(function(){
        $('.dropdown').toggle(500);
    });
    $('#online').hide();
    $(document).on('click', '#new', function() {
        $('#select_znak').html('Новые');
        $('#new').hide();
        $('#online').show();
        $('#all').show();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#all', function() {
        $('#select_znak').html('Все');
        $('#all').hide();
        $('#new').show();
        $('#online').show();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#online', function() {
        $('#select_znak').html('Онлайн');
        $('#online').hide();
        $('#all').show();
        $('#new').show();
    });
```

html:

```
 <span id="select_znak">Онлайн</span>
      <ul class="dropdown">
      <li id="all" value="all"><a href="#">Все</a></li>
      <li id="new" value="new"><a href="#">Новые</a></li>
          <li id="online" value="online"><a href="#">Онлайн</a></li>
      </ul>
```

А вот результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопроса 2

1. Можно ли этот код упростить? Точнее  более чем уверен, что можно не
   повторять 3 раза один и тот же код!
2. Как выбранное значение отправить
       в базу? Типо: `data={ val:$('#select_znak').html()};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все варианты названий держать в массиве – легко добавлять/менять. При клике менять переменную выбранного элемента, и перерисовывать dropdown.

При клике же можно отправлять выбранный вариант куда-то в Google : )

```js
var items=['Все','Новые','Онлайн']
  ,selected = 2
  ,$znak = $('#select_znak')
  ,$drop = $('#drop')
;

function draw(){
  $znak.text( items[ selected]);
  $drop.html( items.map( function( title, i) {
    return i===selected?'':'<li><a href="#" data-item="'+i+'">' +title +'</a></li>';
  }));
}

$znak.on('click', function(){ $drop.toggle(500) });
$drop.on('click', 'a', function(e){ 
  selected = $(e.target).data('item');
  $.ajax({
    data   : { val: items[ selected]},
    method : 'POST',
    url    : "https://google.com" // url вашего скрипта
  });
  draw();
});

draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="select_znak"></span>
<ul id="drop" class="dropdown"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Упростить код можно так:

```js
$('#select_znak').click(function() {
  $('.dropdown').toggle(500);
});
$('#online').hide();

$('.dropdown').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $(this).hide().siblings().show();
  $('#select_znak').html($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="select_znak">Онлайн</span>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li id="all" value="all"><a href="#">Все</a>
  </li>
  <li id="new" value="new"><a href="#">Новые</a>
  </li>
  <li id="online" value="online"><a href="#">Онлайн</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```